# Update PivotTable DataSource with the Office Excel JavaScript API

Tags: pivot-table, office-js, office-addins, excel-interop, excel-addins

I want to use the Excel JavaScript API to update an existing `PivotTable`'s data source, which will be a range in another sheet in the same workbook as the pivot table.  I've only found documentation that shows how to define a `PivotTable`'s data source when [creating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivottable?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-pivottable-getdatasourcestring-member(1)) a new pivot table, not changing an existing `PivotTable`'s data source.

It was possible to change an existing pivot table's data source when developing an Excel COM [add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764063/4664207) and when using [VBA](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-pivot-table-data-source-through-vba/073b0e3b-1a9c-4d7d-bdfc-fc892040f7b6), so I'm surprised to not see an example of it in the JavaScript API documentation so far.

Does anyone know how to update a **existing** `PivotTable`'s data source using the Excel JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the feature: updating an existing PivotTable's data source, you requested, is not a part of the product. Maybe you can add your request here:[Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions).

Comment: Thanks, @SiruiMSFT.  I opened this request:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/update-pivottable-datasource-with-the-office-excel-javascript/idi-p/3565018#M1080.